# Pandas: merging dataframes using a loop - MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few **dataframes** stored inside a **dict** called **my_dict**. The keys of the dict are stored inside a list called **filter_list**.

```
filter_list = ["A", "B", "C", ...]
```

**my_dict[A]** gives me the following result:

```
    links       A
0   Q11@8.jpg   1
1   Q11@11.jpg  1
2   Q11@4.2.jpg 1
3   Q11@4.3.jpg 1
```

**my_dict[B]** gives me the following result:

```
    links       B
0   Q11@8.jpg   1
1   A11@21.jpg  1
2   Q11@42.jpg  1
3   C11@4.jpg   1
```

and so on...

Now I want to **merge** all the dataframes together. I am using an outer-join logic since I want my final dataframe to include all possible links that are present across all dataframes inside the "links" column.

As such, I use a loop to merge them iteratively but I keep getting an error message telling me

> MemoryError:

with no further info. In order to release RAM during my loop I am saving the results to a pickle file, but this doesn't seem to help either. Still I get the same error.

This is the code I am using:

```
for index in tqdm(range(2,len(filter_list))):
    try:
        result = pd.read_pickle("result.pkl")
    except:
        pass
    if index == 2:
        result = pd.merge(my_data[filter_list[0]], my_data[filter_list[1]], on="links", how="outer")
    result = pd.merge(result , my_data[filter_list[index]], on="links", how="outer")
    result.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    result[result.columns[1:]] = result[result.columns[1:]].astype(int)
    result.to_pickle("result.pkl")
    del result
```

Comment: won't  "pd.concat([v for k,v in my_dict.items() if k in filter_list])" achieve exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

I think what you try to achieve can be done with `pd.concat`:

```
result = (pd.concat([my_dict[key].set_index('links') for key in filter_list],
                    axis=1,sort=False)
            .fillna(0).reset_index())
result[result.columns[1:]] = result[result.columns[1:]].astype(int)
```

with your two dataframes A and B, it gives:

```
         index  A  B
0    Q11@8.jpg  1  1
1   Q11@11.jpg  1  0
2  Q11@4.2.jpg  1  0
3  Q11@4.3.jpg  1  0
4   A11@21.jpg  0  1
5   Q11@42.jpg  0  1
6    C11@4.jpg  0  1
```